# Data dictionaries and functionality behind Code Road Map

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

I was looking to a Code Road Map feature that Toad provides which shows dependencies of Objects.

Can anyone tell me on what basis the Toad Generate the Dependencies? I am assuming that  there is a data dictionary view exists `dba_dependencies`  which work at the backend for getting this relation.

So can we write a script to which we pass object name like package name, table_name amongst others that will show the dependency of the object passed by me.

In code Road Map there is an option to generate data for a table ...how does this work?

What is the algorithm behind it? If there is foreign key on the child table and the parent table is empty, how does this work? How it will populate the depending table first and then the child table.

Comment: please ask only 1 question at a time. Also, the second question is too broad & probably only the Toad developers know how they've implemented it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at `user_depencies`/ `dba_dependencies` view structure, querying the view with column `REFERENCED_NAME` equal to the object that you want to query with should provide you with a list of objects where the object you're searching for is referenced.

---

Second question is too broad & probably only the Toad developers know how they've implemented it. The data dictionaries provide information about the various constraints on a table. My guess would be the algorithm looks at data dictionary & has different code paths for handling constraints / master child relations. Another assumption would use of handled exceptions to ensure the data is generated cleanly.

Comment: :Thanks  ,but can you tell me how can i get `reference` of `procedure` inside a `package` ,Because i am trying to create a script to which if i passed the `procedure name` ,which is present inside the package ,then i ll get all the point from which it is called.

Comment: @GauravSoni Oracle doesn't provide that information from the dependencies view, you'll have to do it by yourself by querying `user_source`